# Bypass JSF validation for a UIInput component

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

Here is the issue, JSF validation keeps flipping a field back to the last known value.

We are editing a page where the backing bean already has values.
(frequency = "weekly")

And we are required to show the default value of "please select.." even though that value will not pass validation (yes, I just want to leave the user on the page with the error message).

Is there any way to allow the user to choose "Select.." and not reset it to the last good value?

The user wont be allowed to save obviously, but we want to leave their invalid value selected.

1. User adds new object, selecting proper value from drop down
2. User saves successfully.
3. User Clicks "edit" and displays object with known value ("weekly")
4. User changes "weekly" to "select"
5. User clicks save
6. Validation message is shown (good) but frequency goes back to last value "weekly" (bad, I need it to stay on "Please select.." and let the user fix the drop down manually.

immediate="true" does not work on inputComponents, only commandComponents.

Answer (score 3):

I recognize this, I've reported this more than one year ago as [JSF issue 1299](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1299). This is still not resolved since it has a low priority. This is not specific to all `UIInput` components, but to `MenuRenderer` which is responsible for rendering the HTML `<select>` elements. All other HTML input elements behave as you would expect, the submitted value will be redisplayed (well, which is actually nothing as well).

Since you're already on JSF 2.0, I suggest you to solve this with a little help of `f:ajax` so that the dropdown won't be re-rendered and thus keeps its selection.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="frequency" value="#{bean.frequency}" required="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.frequencies}" />
    <f:ajax render="frequencyMessage" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message id="frequencyMessage" for="frequency" />
```

The additional benefit is that the enduser has instant feedback and this is better for user experience.

Comment: Thanks Balus!
I played with this a bit, but once the user clicks "submit" the value will still revert will it not? Or does that render also apply when the whole page is re-rendered after submit (I would think it does not)

Comment: Use ajax for that as well. Put `<f:ajax/>` inside `h:commandButton`, if necessary along with a `render` on message ids.

Comment: That is a handy trick for live feedback, and shows their mistake right away.
 But even with ajax in my command button with render="messageList" (i use a single messgae box above buttons), the save action still flips the messageList back to the pre-validation value. 
.....
Maybe I will just make the live message read "this value is required and will return to the previous value if not set"